# retriving data from 2 different tables based on selected value in combo box using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

How to retreive data from 2 mysql tables based on value seleted in combobox using jsp.

i tried the following code:

`sqlQuery="select  a.Zone,a.Subzone,b.City from Meter_List  a,Consumer   b  where a.Meterid=b.Meterid="+meterid ;`

can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set in WHERE part:
`a.Meterid = b.Meterid AND a.Meterid = ?`
and use prepared statements (preferably, if available).

Answer (score 0):

You would join the two tables on MeterId and then filter one of the columns with your input, as follows:

```
select a.Zone,a.Subzone,b.City 
from 
    Meter_List a 
    JOIN Consumer b 
    ON a.Meterid = b.Meterid 
where a.Meterid = meterid
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sqlQuery="select a.Zone,a.Subzone,b.City from Meter_List a" +
" INNER JOIN Consumer b ON a.Meterid=b.Meterid" +
" where a.Meterid = "+meterid ;
```

or

```
sqlQuery="select a.Zone,a.Subzone,b.City from Meter_List a,Consumer b where a.Meterid=b.Meterid AND a.Meterid="+meterid ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
sqlQuery="select a.Zone,a.Subzone, b.City from Meter_List AS a,
LEFT JOIN Consumer AS b ON (b.Meterid=a.Meterid) where a.Meterid=" + meterid ;
```

or

```
sqlQuery="select a.Zone,a.Subzone, b.City from Meter_List AS a,
INNER JOIN Consumer AS b ON (a.Meterid=b.Meterid) where a.Meterid=" + meterid ;
```